# some code is visible on wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

there is a code thats showing on top of wordpress pages... i dont remember making any change that makes this code be visible!

```
{if $options->theme->general->favicon != ""} {/if} {includePart parts/seo} {googleAnalytics $options->theme->google->analyticsTrackingId} {wpHead} {!$options->theme->header->customJsCode} {var $searchFormClass = ""} {if $elements->unsortable[search-form]->display} {var $searchFormClass = $elements->unsortable[search-form]->option('type') != "" ? "search-form-type-".$elements->unsortable[search-form]->option('type') : "search-form-type-1"} {/if} {* usefull for inline scripts like facebook social plugins scripts, etc... *} {doAction ait-html-body-begin} {if $wp->isPage}
{else}
{/if}
{includePart parts/social-icons} {includePart parts/languages-switcher} {includePart "parts/woocommerce-cart"} {includePart portal/parts/header-resources}
{!html_entity_decode($wp->description)}
```

any suggestion to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

You must have some php code that is being interpreted as a string and not run. I would check your error logs and see if you can track down the error. Change themes and see if you still get the unwanted text.  If you don't, there's a problem with your theme. If that doesn't work, disable plugins one by one and see if the issue is resolved. Then you may be able to narrow it down to a bad plugin.